# Linq Master Detail with Master Primary Key generated with instead of Insert trigger on SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, linq, linq-to-sql, triggers

I have a scenario where my primary key in my master table is not an identity column. It is generated on a "Instead of Insert" trigger within an MS SQL Server database. The primary key is generated in a varchar format of XYZ-11-001.  I am trying to do an insert on the master table then add detail records using Linq.  I keep getting an error of "Cannot insert the value NULL into column 'ParentID', table 'MyDB.dbo.Child'; column does not allow nulls. INSERT fails." I do have my Primarykey/ForeignKey relationship setup correctly.

My simplified code is as follows:

```
using (DBDataContext context = new DBDataContext())
{
    ParentTable parent = new ParentTable();
    parent.FirstName = "Joe";
    parent.LastName = "Blow";

    master.Childs = new System.Data.Linq.EntitySet<child>();
    int index = 0;

    foreach (childObj in ChildrenObj) 
    {
        Index++;
        Child child = new Child();
        parent.Childs.Add(child);
        child.ID = index;  //Foreignkey + ID are Primarykey of the child table 
        child.FirstName = childObj.FirstName;
        child.LastName = childObj.LastName;


    }

    context.parents.InsertOnSubmit(parent);
    context.SubmitChanges();
}
```

I've tried setting the child.Parent_ID to the parent.ID value,  but it doesn't seem to get updated after the "Instead of Insert" trigger fires (even if I do a InsertOnSubmit before adding the child objects).  I've tried setting it to an arbitrary value, but it complains because it doesn't update the child.NonIdendityColumn ForeignKey value.  Is what I am trying to do even possible?  It seems quite trivial to use non generated ID values for a primary key within a database.

Any help would be much appreciated.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Q: "Is what I am trying to do even possible?"

A: Yes, at the DB level...

You'd use the OUTPUT clause as I [described here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8226470/sql-server-understand-scope-identity/8228825#8228825), but how you would implement that through LINQ I don't know.