# SQL Server understand SCOPE_IDENTITY()

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I have this piece of code in a stored procedure:

```
BEGIN
    SET @UserId = NULL;
    IF (@Username IS NOT NULL)
    BEGIN
        EXECUTE SP_ADD_USER @Username, @UserId OUTPUT;
    END
    EXECUTE SP_ADD_ALERT @Name, @AlertType, @AlertId OUTPUT;
    INSERT INTO AlertLogs (Datastamp, AlertID, UserID, NotificationMessage) 
        VALUES (@Datastamp, @AlertId, @UserId, @EmailMessage);
    SET @AlertLogId = SCOPE_IDENTITY();
END
```

`@AlertLogId` is an output parameter that I want to be assigned to the result of the last insert in `AlertLogs` table. Do I have to include

```
INSERT INTO AlertLogs (Datastamp, AlertID, UserID, NotificationMessage) 
        VALUES (@Datastamp, @AlertId, @UserId, @EmailMessage);
```

in a new block (a new begin/end scope) in order for `SCOPE_IDENTITY()` to work correctly ? 
(and not report for example the last ID of an inserted record done in `SP_ADD_ALERT` for example ?)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In your query, `SCOPE_IDENTITY()` is going to return the last entered identity value into the database, for this scope.

In this instance, it will be the identity for the `AlertLogs` table, if this has an identity.

> A scope is a module: a stored procedure, trigger, function, or batch.
>   Therefore, two statements are in the same scope if they are in the
>   same stored procedure, function, or batch.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190315.aspx

Comment: This is what I expected also. EXECUTE SP_ADD_ALERT executes in another scope so that wouldn't be considered in any case, even if that has also inserted identity values

Comment: Yes it states on the msdn site that the two statements must be within the same stored procedure, function etc. Although I don't see why you would use `SCOPE_IDENTITY` in a function as you cannot `INSERT` or `EXEC`

Comment: Can a function do anything that would cause a trigger to insert something, and if so, would that insert affect the value of SCOPE_IDENTITY() in the function?

Comment: @Matt Sach - triggers are a different scope (as indicated in the quote above), so no, a trigger can't affect a `SCOPE_IDENTITY()` call (other than one which is also placed within the body of the trigger).

Comment: @MattSach - Table Triggers can be called by an `INSERT`, `UPDATE` or `DELETE`. A UDF cannot invoke any of these commands.

Answer (score 1):

You can also use an [OUTPUT clause](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177564.aspx) in your insert statement. This means you don't need to worry about scope and you make other (non-identity) information available from the inserted table.

Consider this simple table:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[SampleTable](
    [ID] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [InsertDate] [datetime] NOT NULL,
    [Name] [nvarchar](100) NULL
) ON [PRIMARY]
```

With this default added:

```
ALTER TABLE [dbo].[SampleTable] 
    ADD CONSTRAINT [DF_SampleTable_Inserted]  
        DEFAULT (getdate()) FOR [InsertDate]
```

You can get values for both the default and the identity from the insert operation.

```
DECLARE @InsertedDetails TABLE (ID int, InsertDate DateTime);

INSERT INTO SampleTable ([Name])
    OUTPUT inserted.ID, inserted.InsertDate 
        INTO @InsertedDetails 
    VALUES ('Fred');

DECLARE @ID int; 
DECLARE @InsertDate datetime;
SELECT @ID = ID, @InsertDate = InsertDate FROM @InsertedDetails;

PRINT @ID;
PRINT @InsertDate;
```

Here I've just pulled the values out of the table variable and printed them.